# Starting to program in iOS in Xcode 4.2, what iPhone should I get?

Tags: iphone, version

I am new to iOS development: I am reading the guides, purchased macmini, playing around and coding in Xcode 4.2. I have developer account and want to get a used iPhone to run my apps on.

Now I am not sure what iPhone to purchase: I am concerned about whether I would be able to install new iOS on iPhone 4 if I decide to buy iPhone 4. I am also concerned that I won't be able to use any features 4S, but from the looks of it it doesn't seem like there are too many features. Obviously I'd rather spend $250-300 on iPhone 4 vs $400-450 on iPhone 4S, but if it is a better investment to get 4S I'd fork out the money.

My questions are:

1) Will I be able to install new iOS on iPhone 4?
2) Will iPhone 4 will be in any way detrimental for my development? (I am interested in geo-aware apps in particular)

I want to make as informed decision on buying the phone as I can.

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Thank you!

Comment: That was fast and helpful. Thank you, guys!

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 4.5: use always the latest version as it is required to submit applications on the App Store and use latest iOS features. Also Xcode 4.5 supports new compiler and some very useful new Objective-C syntax like literals.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes you can install the newest OS on the 4
2) No it shouldn't be detrimental, there may be one or two small things you are unable to test on the device, but Xcode has a simulator.

Buy an iPhone 4, and you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

1)Yes, iOS 6 will be available on the iPhone 4 (probably later on this year).

2) Depends - iOS 6 contains 3D Maps, which is **not** supported by iPhone 4. Siri is also only supported on iPhone 4S. I believe you would be okay with geo-aware related features though.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Will I be able to install new iOS on iPhone 4?

If you check out [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/13/ios-6-compatibility-supported-devices/) article, it says that iOS 6 supports all devices back to the iPhone 3GS (including the 3GS) so you can install it on the iPhone 4.

> 2) Will iPhone 4 will be in any way detrimental for my development? (I am interested in geo-aware apps in particular)

Since the iPhone 4 has the same operating system as the iPhone 4S, they are almost identical development-wise. The only differences would be in the hardware (4S has slightly more accurate GPS, etc.). You can also take advantage of the new iOS 6 features like Passbook and Facebook integration (except for the new 3D maps feature)

Hope this helps!